# setup LVM to combine local and network block devices?

Tags: storage, lvm, storage-area-network

Because my local RAID-based logical volume is not big enough, I am thinking to extend it to a network block device. I am aware that when read/write to the network block device, the performance is lower. However, the bigger risky thing: in cases of network instability, the data in this network-spanning volume may be corrupted. So my question is, how robust is LVM to deal with this setup? What other suggestions do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You need all the pvs of a volume group, unless some of them are mirrors of each other.

Keeping the disks in a vg as similar as possible, such as all being local disk, is easier to manage.

You can extend a volume group onto new bigger disks of some kind, move the volumes to the new disks, and reduce the vg by the old disk.